# sonarqube 5.2 background tasks sometimes fail with no log

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

It seems that over half of the time I try to execute analysis using Sonar Runner 2.4 on several different projects that the analysis completes successfully but the publish (via the background task) to SonarQube fails.  There is no log that I can find with relevant information on the SonarQube server for the failed tasks - at least I can't find any.  I am new to SonarQube.  The SonarQube 5.2 server is on Windows Server 2012 R2 using SQL Server 2012(SP1) database.

Comment: What do the _sonar-runner_ logs say ? Is there any task shown under Administration - Projects - Background Tasks ?

Comment: You should find useful logs in the Administration -> Projects -> Background Tasks page. You can access to any logs of tasks.

Comment: Yes, @n_stan and Julien L,  tasks are shown under Administration>Projects>Background Tasks but only the one marked Success have logs associated with them.  The tasks marked Failed have no link to Logs.

Comment: Can you share _sonar-runner_ debug logs (`sonar.verbose=true`) and [server debug logs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Server+Log+Management) when the analysis is executed ?

Comment: The contents of the server log do not show anything but information regarding the last successful task - not the task that failed.

Comment: The sonar-runner log is too big to share but it shows DEBUG  - Publish  INFO -  ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL

Answer (score 3):

The answer is the solution stated in the related [SonarQube 5.3 Background Task Fails with No Log in Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762115/sonarqube-5-3-background-task-fails-with-no-log-in-dashboard?lq=1) . There were several SonarQube servers, which I was unaware of when I originally posted, accessing the same database.  When those other instances were shut down there were no more failures in the background tasks.