# Is it possible to run two sonarqube instances on different machines which points single database

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

Is it possible to run two sonarqube 5.3 instances on different machines which points single database.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not, and with in any version of SonarQube. Doing so will confuse both SonarQube instances and will mess them both.
Olivier

Comment: If you do, you can run into problems such as http://stackoverflow.com/a/34813756/4940316